# Wiring 240 V single-phase AC induction motor to enable operation forward and reverse on a 2-post ramp pulley system

Tags: ac, induction-motor, single-phase

I installed a single phase motor on a car ramp. I need the motor to operate forward and reverse, so the ramp goes up or down.

I understand this is possible with the use of two contactors. I need the wiring schematic to do this.

Information from motor:

[image: Information on motor]

Wiring diagram that came with motor:

[image: Wiring diagram that came with motor]

Comment: unfortunately my research so far has been a blank. it's a single phase motor with a start capacitor and run capacitor. I think it's possible to run the motor in either direction with the use of two contactors,one for forward(up)control and the other for reverse(down) control of ramp. In saying that I struggle to find any info on how this would be wired to enable such control.

Comment: If the motor has a label or metal plate attached to it or if you can find information from the manufacturer about connections and reverse operation you may find that reverse operation is possible and how to do that. With the information you have provided in the question and even with the information that you added in a comment that should be in the question, there is no way to determine if reverse operation is even possible. Most single-phase motors are designed for a specific purpose. If you don't know where the motor came from or how it was used or anything else useful, no one can help.

Comment: reverse operation is possible on motor as manufacturers diagram confirms this. My problem is wiring motor to do both. Unfortunately having an issue uploading pictures to this thread

Comment: This might help: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy

Comment: You need a relay or contactor with two normally open and two normally closed contacts. Replace the link connections for one direction with normally open contacts and the connections for the other direction with normally closed contacts. Make sure that the direction can not be changed with the motor shaft turning fast enough to activate the centrifugal switch.

Comment: @tlfong01, a project on a toy buggy using DC motors is not appropriate for learning how to run a mains powered, single-phase induction motor in forward and reverse. That's being silly.

Comment: @Sean - Hi, This topic has specific safety considerations, so local assistance may be *required*. But with your added information, I will take the question "off hold" in case answers are now possible. To help other readers, here are a couple of links, since the wiring diagram image in the question is quite difficult to read. (a) [Manufacturer's page for the AMAS-SR series, including AMAS-SR 112M4](https://amtecs.co.uk/motors/single-phase/start-run-capacitor.html). (b) [Connection diagram PDF linked from that page](https://amtecs.co.uk/pub/media/wysiwyg/TechnicalData/Connection_Diagrams.pdf).

Comment: Charles cowie thank you very much for your reply to my post.this is exactly the sort of information I was looking for so can't thank you enough

Comment: @Transistor, Thanks so much for pointing out my silly mistake. I appreciate your help to improve my answers. Looking back my couple of hundred answers, there is only other similar case that another reader pointed out my seemingly silly mistake. I confess that I do have one associated weakness in this regard that I need to keep in mind. But I do notice one very strange thing common to both cases.  It is a bit complicated, so I would not think it worth your and my time go deeper to find out the cause. I will definitely explain it if one day I found a similar case and I can explain. Cheers.

Comment: #Sean, My apologies for giving a silly answer to your question. I confess that I did not understand your situation, but wrongly thought that your problem was simply reversing the motor direction. I am glad that you have now solved the problem. Cheers.

Comment: Sean, just an enquiry. I have a similar situation with a lathe. Did you eventually have a conclusion on the forward and reverse situation. Regards JohnK

Answer (score 1):

You need a relay or contactor with two normally open and two normally closed contacts. Replace the link connections for one direction with normally open contacts and the connections for the other direction with normally closed contacts. Make sure that the direction can not be changed with the motor shaft turning fast enough to activate the centrifugal switch.

You may have difficulty finding a contactor or relay that is suitable for 5 Hp / 3.7 kW a reversing motor starter would be better.

[image]